# Android opengl Touch Event

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch-event

I'm trying to make a program that create a signal base on the position where i'm touching on the screen.That means i can change every point from the horizontally line ,with my finger.
But i can't have you do that , beacuse it will be complicated for you , so i want a circle to follow my finger.
I'm mentioning that i'm not using MyGLSurfaceView class, i'm using only MyGLRenderer class (named GL_Render.java):

```
public class GL_Render implements Renderer
{
    private Context context;


    private Polygon myPoly = new Polygon();
    private desen myDesen= new desen();

    private MainActivity mySignal = new MainActivity();
    private MainActivity myAngle = new MainActivity();
    private MainActivity myZoom = new MainActivity();



    public GL_Render(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {       
        float ZOOM =myZoom.zoom;
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();   // reset the matrix to its default state

        // When using GL_MODELVIEW, you must set the view point
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f,     0,   -3,      0f,    0f,      0f,    0f,  1.0f, 0.0f);
      //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY,   upZ);


     //   float ratio = (float)( width / height  ) ;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);        // set matrix to projection mode
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                        // reset the matrix to its default state
        if(ZOOM==0){
        gl.glFrustumf(0f, -1f, -1, 1, 3, 7);  // apply the projection matrix
        //gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        }
        else
        {
              gl.glFrustumf(0f, -1f/(2*ZOOM), -1, 1, 3, 7);  // apply the projection matrix
            //gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);

        }

        myDesen.Desen(gl);



        if(ZOOM!=0)
        {
        float l2[] =
            {
                (float)0.5/(2*ZOOM),  0.5f, 0.0f,
                (float)0.5/(2*ZOOM), -0.5f, 0.0f 
            };


        myPoly.Polygon(l2);
        myPoly.draw(gl,1,0,0);
        }
        else{
            float l2[] =
                {
                    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 
                    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f 
                };              
            myPoly.Polygon(l2);
            myPoly.draw(gl,1,0,0);
        }

                    // Create the moving Circle here if possible:



        }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {

        // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes
        // such as screen rotations
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // make adjustments for screen ratio
        float ratio = (float)( width / height  ) ;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);        // set matrix to projection mode
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                        // reset the matrix to its default state

        gl.glFrustumf(0f, -1f, -1, 1, 3, 7);  // apply the projection matrix
        //gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) 
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        myPoly=new Polygon();
    }

    private void GL_Prepare(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);     
    }

    private void GL_Finish(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }


}
```

Comment: That's a very unclear description of what you're trying to do. Unrelatedly, where's your question?

Comment: Sory for my poor description, my question is how can i make a circle folow my finger with out MyGLSurfaceView class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what view you use whether it's GlSurfaceView or not you need a Touch Listener. You can then use the Touch Listener in the standard way the only difference is you'll need to convert your touch points from screen coordinates to your opengl scene coordinates.

Comment: So my Touch Listener will be in MainActivity.java?

Comment: Then how can i convert them?

Comment: Your touch listener will be on whatever you are using to display. The activity isn't a view at some point you have to have a view of some kind to display, that's what will use the touch listener. 

To convert you can either do the matrix transformations yourself or you can use GLU.gluUnProject()

Comment: Can you give me an example of a TouchListener?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html

Here is google's example of doing touch in opengl with surfaceView http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html